# Limit of $\exp(f(x))$ implies existence of limit of $f(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analytic-functions

My question comes from this observation: If $f(x)$ is a complex-valued, continuous function on interval $(0,1)$, and we know that limit of $f(x)$ at $x=1$ exists and finite, then we know that limit of $\exp(f(x))$ at $x=1$ exists, since $exp(x)$ function is continuous.

I guess that the converse still holds: if we know that limit of $\exp(f(x))$ at $x=1$ exists and it is not 0, then limit of $f(x)$ at $x=1$ exists. But I am stuck here, since the logarithmic function is not single-valued. Thus, even if we know the limit of $\exp(f(x))$ at $x=1$, we don't even know what the limit of $f(x)$ at $x=1$ could be. How do I approach this problem?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is just a hint: Without loss of generality, assume $\lim_{x\rightarrow1-}\exp(f(x))=1$. If $f(x)$ does no have a limit at $1-$, then, there is a sequence of integers $m_n$ and an increasing sequence $x_n\rightarrow1$ such that  $|f(x_n) - 2\pi im_n|\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$, and $|m_{n+1}-m_n|\geq1$

Comment: The continuity of $f$ implies that within the interval $[x_n,x_{n+1}]$ there is a point $y_n$ such that $|f(y_n)-f(x_n)|=\frac12|f(x_{n+1})-f(x_n)|$. Clearly $y_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}1$ but $\inf_n|\exp(f(y_n))-1|>0$.

Comment: @Oliver Diaz Can you be more explicit on how to find the sequence x_n and m_n as you claim, and how you derive the contradiction?

Comment: I leave all details to you, but the ideas is that since $\lim_{x\rightarrow1-}e^{f(x)}=1$, then in a small interval of the form $(a,1)$ $f(x)$ takes values that are closed to integer multiples of $2\pi i$ (because $e^z=1$ iff $z\in 2pi i\mathbb{Z}$). If $f(x)$ fails to converge to $1$, then in $(a,1)$ $f(x)$ *visits* neighborhoods (say of length $1/2$ of different elements in $2\pi i\mathbb{Z}$. Start with some $x_1$ such that $f(x_1)\in B(2\pi im_1;\frac14)$, then you con find $m_2\neq m_1$ and $x_2>x_1$ such that $f(x_2)\in B(2\pi im_2;\frac14)$. Repeat this argument (to be continued)

Comment: (continuation) Notice that the $m_n$'s are not necessarily distinct, but that $|m_{n+1}-m_k|\geq 1$. To convince yourself that this is doable, notice that on a small neighborhood $(a,1)$ you have $f(x)\in\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}B(2\pi in;\frac14)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The heart of the problem is to show that when $e^x$ and $e^y$ are close to each other, then there exists an integer $n$ such that $x$ and $y + 2 \pi i n$ are close to each other. This can be done by showing that for a suitable branch of the logarithm, $\log e^x$ and $\log e^y$ are close to each other. Continuity of $f$ will imply that the $n$'s that appear are $0$, and the existence of the limit of $f$ at $1$ will follow from Cauchy's criterion.

Formally, let $a$ be the limit of $e^{f(x)}$ at $1$. Let $\epsilon > 0$. Then there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $x \in (1-\delta, 1)$ we have $|e^{f(x)} - a| < \epsilon$. In particular for $x, y \in (1-\delta, 1)$ we have $|e^{f(x)} - e^{f(y)}| < 2 \epsilon$.

Take a branch of the logarithm such that the branch cut does not contain $a$, and call it $\log$. Take any $\epsilon' > 0$. Then there exists $\delta' > 0$ such that $|e^{f(x)} - e^{f(y)}| < \delta'$ implies $|\log e^{f(x)}- \log e^{f(y)}| < \epsilon'$.

Now take $\epsilon = \delta' / 2$ above. Then for $x, y \in (1-\delta, 1)$ we have $|\log e^{f(x)}- \log e^{f(y)}| < \epsilon'$. In particular, there exists an integer $n$ depending on $x, y$ and $\epsilon'$. such that $|f(x) - f(y) + 2 \pi i n| < \epsilon'$.

We show that $n$ is $0$ as soon as $\epsilon'$ is small enough. Clearly when $\epsilon' < \pi$ there is at most one such $n$ for every $x$ and $y$, which consequently does not depend on $\epsilon'$. That, is taking $\epsilon' = 0.1$ we obtain a function $n(x, y)$ defined for $x, y \in (1-\delta, 1)$.

We show that $n$ is locally constant. Indeed, by continuity of $f$, if $x$ or $y$ are changed a tiny bit, say to $x', y'$, the inequality $|f(x') - f(y') + 2 \pi i n(x, y)| < 0.1$ still holds.

Because $n(x, y)$ is a locally constant function on $(1-\delta, 1) \times (1-  \delta, 1)$, it is constant. Taking $x = y$ shows that the constant is $0$.

We have now shown that for all $\epsilon' > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $x, y \in (1-\delta, 1)$ implies $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon'$. By Cauchy's criterion, $f$ has a limit at $1$.